# Adding Project as Submodule prompt an error Module YapDatabse not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xmppframework, yapdatabase

I am using [ChatSecure](https://github.com/ChatSecure/ChatSecure-iOS) as a submodule of my project. I have added it to my project. But it is showing an error in pods of ChatSecure but when I am running only ChatSecure it is working fine and running on my iPhone.
[image]

And sometimes it is showing the long list of errors[image]

Anyone previously faced this problem? I am trying to resolve error in this project from last 3 days. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

Also, Please Make sure your **Chatsecure** Projects **Pods** are updated else go to Chatsecure project path and run

```
 pod update --verbose
```

Comment: no such file or directory: '/Users/muhammadraza/Documents/vd-work-apps/ChatSecureTest/ChatSecure-iOS/Carthage/Checkouts/SignalProtocolC/libsignal-protocol-c/src/curve25519/ed25519/additions/ge_is_small_order.c'